# Citrix Endpoint Analysis crashes on macOS Catalina

Tags: macos, catalina

It gets stuck at downloading EPA Libraries and then crashes with the message

**EPA fail**

I have tried rebooting and clearing browser history.

Has anyone else experienced this? Can anyone help with this situation?

Using: MacBook Mid 2012 running macOS Catalina 10.15.7.

[image: Screenshot of CitrixEndpointAnalysis window showing a download in progress]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Could you check `~/Library/Application Support/Citrix/EPAPlugin/epaplugin.log`? It may contain relevant information. Is this  your work Mac? If that's the case, have you contacted your IT department, or Citrix support?

Comment: No its my personal mac and checked log file nothing significant, its just try to connect and get failed